# 'Debugging' visual studio code .natvis based custom view objects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, natvis

I would like to provide some .natvis file based C++ custom view objects for Visual Studio Code. It is not working as expected out of the box and the definitions used in the .natvis file are not used to display the intended objects during a debugging session. I added the custom .navis file to the launch.json and followed all best practices I could find.

Now I'm at the point where some feedback about the parsed .natvis content would be helpful to find the error. Is it possible to get log outputs or more about these definitions in a Visual Studio Code session to be able to find my error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is, but I don't have experience with VS Code, only Visual Studio. But presumably you have Visual Studio installed if you are using natvis? If not then maybe you could download it, to fix your natvis errors.

In Visual Studio go to

```
Tools/Options/Debugging/Output Window/General Output Settings/Natvis Diagnostic Messages
```

Set to `Error` or `Verbose`

Error messages appear in the output window when you start debugging your program. I found that you get one error message at a time. So if your natvis file has several errors it will take a while to fix them all.

Comment: Yes, great ! So VSCode does not seem to support natvis analysis, but this workaround works perfectly. Thank you very much !

Comment: @FrankBlabu: Visual studio code, with the microsoft C++ extension, does support natvis analysis. In your launch.json look for the "visualizerFile" and "showDisplayString" settings. See also:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_visualizerfile